# Communicate Cron job with other docker container

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, cron

I have a docker-compose app as the following:

```
networks:
  app-network:
      driver: bridge
      
services:
  schedulermicroservicejs:
    container_name: schedulermicroservicejs
    hostname: schedulermicroservicejs
    image: somoe-image
    ports:
        - "8087:8087"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: SchedulerMicroserviceJS/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
        - activitiesmicroservice
    networks:
        - app-network
  cron:
    build: ./SchedulerMicroserviceJS/dockerized-cron
    networks:
        - app-network
```

I want to know if it is possible to communicate the cron job with the scheduler microservice. The cron job was done using an ubuntu image:

```
# Pulling Ubuntu image
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Updating packages and installing cron
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install cron -y

# Installing node js
RUN apt-get install nodejs -y && apt-get install npm -y

# Creating directory for the script
RUN mkdir /script

# Setting script directory
WORKDIR /script

# Run npm init -y to create package.json
RUN npm init -y

# Install axios package
RUN npm install axios

# Create a file called script.js
RUN echo "const axios = require('axios');" >> script.js
RUN echo "const microserviceURL = 'http://schedulermicroservicejs:8087/api/scheduler';" >> script.js
RUN echo "axios.get(microserviceURL)" >> script.js
RUN echo "  .then(res => console.log('Schedule done successfully'))" >> script.js
RUN echo "  .catch(e => console.error(e));" >> script.js
RUN echo "console.log('Schedule done successfully');" >> script.js

# Copying script file into the container.
COPY date-script.sh .

# Giving executable permission to the script file.
RUN chmod +x date-script.sh

# Adding crontab to the appropiate location
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/my-cron-file

# Giving executable permission to crontab file
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/my-cron-file

# Running crontab
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/my-cron-file

# Creating entry point for cron 
ENTRYPOINT ["cron", "-f"]
```

Here is the crontab:

```
* * * * * root bash date-script.sh
```

Here it is the date-script.sh:

```
cd /script
#!/bin/sh
# It's Monday, so execute npm run scheduler
node script.js
```

This takes too much to load because of the installation of node, so I was wondering if it is possible to communicate the cron with the scheduler microservice by accessing the container and running the npm commands in the schedulermicroservice because it is already running node. But because each container runs its own localhost and vm, I caan't just access the microservice directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's feasable, but definitely hard and not the best approach.

From my understanding your cron only does a `GET` request to your Microservice. The `curl` CLI would definetely be lighter and easier to use rather than running a Javascript file to do this which requires Node. Moreover, [official Node images](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) already exist on Dockerhub with Node pre-installed.

Bu, why does it take too much time to load anyways ? The build of the image yes, but once the container runs only the cron runs, right ? It shouldn't be that slow.

Also, some slight improvements :

- Don't echo the whole `script.js` file, create it on your host and use `COPY`
- `WORKDIR` creates the folder if it doesn't exist, so no need to run `mkdir` before.

Comment: Thank you for your response but i ended up implementing a node module called `node-cron` I just start the cron task when the microservice starts.